# Prove that $\infty+c$ is not an indeterminate form, where $c$ is a real number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

So, here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions. Suppose that $f(x) \to c$ as $x \to x_0$ and $g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to x_0$. Suppose that $c$ is finite. Then, $f(x)+g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to x_0$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $M>0$. We have to prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that:

$$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)+g(x)| > M$$

Now, we know that:

$$|f(x)+g(x)| \geq |g(x)|-|f(x)|$$

and we want that right-hand side to be greater than $M$. In other words, $|g(x)| > |f(x)| + M$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that:

$$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x)-c| < \epsilon$$

$$\implies |f(x)| < |c| + \epsilon$$

Now, let $\delta_2 > 0$ exist such that:

$$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x)| > M + |c| + \epsilon$

Define $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Then:

$$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)+g(x)| \geq |g(x)| - |f(x)| > M + |c| + \epsilon - |c| - \epsilon = M$$

Since the existence of the desired $\delta$ has been established, this proves the desired result.

Does the proof above work? If not, why? How could I, then, improve it?

Comment: actually, since you're trying to prove $f(x) + g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to x_0$, you have to prove that $0< |x-x_0|< \delta \implies f(x)+g(x) > M$ (without the absolute values). This is because you want to prove the function itself goes to $\infty$, not its absolute value apporahes $\infty$.

Comment: Uh the definition given in my text is as follows: $lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \infty \iff \forall M>0: \exists \delta > 0: 0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)| > M$. Like, that's what I'm working with so I assume that it applies for this problem.

Comment: you mean $|f(x)| > M$?

Comment: Yeap lol, had a retard moment

Comment: are you sure? because that definition is not the correct one. According to that definition, the function $f(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ would satisfy $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \infty$, when in fact the limit should be $-\infty$. It would also assign a limit of $\infty$ to functions whose limit doesn't exist (for example consider $e^x \sin x$ as $x \to \infty$. This has no limit, because changes sign repeatedly, but its absolute value does have a limit $\infty$).

Comment: Yeap, that was precisely the definition given in the text. I found it quite weird but decided that the author would probably go into detail in that separately. This is Richard Silverman's Modern Calculus and Analytic Geometry that I'm using right now

Comment: @peek-a-boo In some contexts, we use this definition for a limit of $\infty$. Sometimes we don’t need to think about $\infty$ as being signed, but instead as just “really big”.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Also, no, $e^x \sin x$ would not have a limit of $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$ since $|e^x \sin x| = 0$ for $x \in 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AJY I see. If that's the case, then ok... it's just not a definition I've seen in any book (Spivak,Rudin, Duistermaat). And about the exponential thing yes of course, you're right; clearly I have messed up what I intended to say (and at this point I don't even remember what I intended to say lol)

Comment: Hmmm so the definition would be different in those books? I'll check them out after I'm done with this one. But in the meantime, using the definition I've posted above, is my argument correct?

Comment: by the way, I made a mistake with the references lol. I meant Spivak, Rudin and Amann & Escher. Spivak's text is called Calculus. Rudin's (first) text is Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Amann and Escher's text is Analysis (Volume 1)

Comment: Oh nice, I have Spivak's Calculus and Amann & Escher's Analysis books. I've been too afraid to use the Analysis texts because idk if my background is good enough to work through them. I've only done Calculus intuitively and I have experience in proofs but not sure if it would be wise to jump straight into those analysis texts

Comment: I actually haven't thoroughly read Amann and Escher's Volume 1 (I'm currently reading their volume 3). However, Spivak's text is an absolute gem. When I started studying it, I only did calculus intuitively, and I was able to do all the routine calculations of calculating derivatives, basic integrals etc, but didn't have any proof background. But from your post, it seems that you're more than capable of reading through Spivak (doesn't mean its easy of course). Also, the problems were at times hard, but interesting.

Comment: (as you can guess, I'm very biased toward Spivak's Calculus. It's really the one book which made me want to learn more)

Comment: That's fine, you've given me enough reason to look into the book and try to learn from it. I'm really enjoying Silverman's text because I enjoy the memes that he drops into the text so often. I might do Spivak's text afterwards to give myself a good challenge.

Comment: yes of course, you should stick with a book, and learn as much you can out of it

Comment: That's what I'm trying my best to do. I'm learning this now so that I have a bit of an easier time doing other bits of math when I go to university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks correct! One small thing perhaps worth noting is that you didn’t have to do this for all $\epsilon > 0$, but could’ve just chosen $\delta > 0$ such that $0<|x - x_0| < \delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x) - c| < 7, |g(x)| > M + |c| + 7$, or any other positive number. In fact, $f$ doesn’t even need to have a limit at $x_0$, it just needs to bounded in some neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Oh nice! I will try proving it for a function that is bounded in some neighbourhood of $x_0$. I probably won't remember that theorem specifically, though, cos I suck at remembering things. I'm, like, working straight off of the definition most of the time

Comment: I don’t know if it’s a terribly important thing to know in itself, it’s just good sometimes once you’ve written a proof to take stock of what assumptions you used in the process. The general idea in this is that if $g$ is going to $\infty$, and $f$ is only so big around there, then infinite plus bounded is still infinite.

Comment: Yeap. The general ideas are easy to grasp. They're intuitively obvious, even. I just need to revisit the assumptions being made so that I'm not being stupid when applying a theorem in solving a problem. I've mostly been covering up the proofs given in the book and have been trying to prove the results on my own. So, I sort of only pay attention to the assumptions when I need to use them in proving the result